# How can I make inserting a node in "insert" sorted?

Tags: fortran

I need this code here to add the nodes in a sorted manner, how can I do that? I also need that the new node is not allocated in the main program.
Instead, pass only the integer argument, and use allocate to
create a new node when needed.

```
call insert(the_list,1)
call insert(the_list,5)
call insert(the_list,3)
```

```
  implicit none

  type node
     integer :: value
     type(node),pointer :: next
  end type node

  type list
     type(node),pointer :: head
  end type list
  
  type(list) :: the_list
  type(node),pointer :: node_ptr

  nullify(the_list%head)

  allocate(node_ptr); node_ptr%value = 1
  call insert(the_list,node_ptr)
  allocate(node_ptr); node_ptr%value = 5
  call insert(the_list,node_ptr)
  allocate(node_ptr); node_ptr%value = 3
  call insert(the_list,node_ptr)
  call print(sort(the_list))


contains
  
  subroutine insert( the_list,new_node )
    implicit none
    ! parameters
    type(list),intent(inout) :: the_list
    type(node),intent(inout),pointer :: new_node
    ! local
    type(node),pointer :: current,previous

    if (.not.associated(the_list%head)) then
       nullify(new_node%next)
       the_list%head => new_node
    else
      current => the_list%head
      do while ( associated(current%next) )
          previous => current
          current => current%next
      end do
      nullify(new_node%next)
      current%next => new_node
    end if
    
    
  end subroutine insert
  
  
  integer function length( the_list )
    implicit none
    type(list),intent(in) :: the_list
    ! local
    type(node),pointer :: current

    if (.not.associated(the_list%head)) then
       length = 0
    else
       current => the_list%head       
       do
          length = length+1
          if (.not.associated(current%next)) exit
          current => current%next
       end do
    end if
  end function length

  subroutine print(the_list)
    implicit none
    type(list),intent(in) :: the_list
    type(node),pointer :: current

    write(*,'("List: [ ")',advance="no")
    if (associated(the_list%head)) then
       current => the_list%head
       do while (associated(current))
          write(*,'(i1",")',advance="no") current%value
          if (.not.associated(current%next)) exit
          current => current%next
       end do
    end if
    write(*,'(x"]")')

  end subroutine print
  
end Program LinkedList
```

Comment: Welcome, I suggest taking the [tour]. Be aware that Fortran 90 is a very old revision of the standard. Fortran 95 fixed several problems with that old version and Fortran 2003 and later added many features for derived types. Do not be confused by the file extension`.f90`, it does not mean Fortran 90, it just denotes free-form source files.

Comment: Yeah but i need to use fortran 90 (.F90) file

Comment: I just tried to explain you in my previous comment, that the `.f90` or `.F90` file extension does NOT mean Fortran 90. It means free source form. This source form can contain source of any Fortran standard version from Fortran 90 to Fortran 2018. Be aware that most compilers only consider Fortran 95 and later.

Comment: Does this answer help? [inserting in singly linked list in ascending order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26352007/inserting-in-singly-linked-list-in-ascending-order). It's C not Fortran, but the principle is the same.

Comment: @veryreverie So I kinda get the concept but I'm trying to modify an existing code which is making me limited about the changes

Answer (score 1):

In order to insert nodes in ascending order, you first need a subroutine which can insert a node at an arbitrary location in the list. This should looks something like

```
subroutine insert_node(old, new)
  type(node), pointer, intent(inout) :: old
  type(node), pointer, intent(inout) :: new

  if (.not.associated(old)) then
    nullify(new%next)
    old => new
  else
    new%next => old
    old => new
  endif
end subroutine
```

And will take a list which looks like `... -> foo -> old -> bar -> ...` and give `... -> foo -> new -> old -> bar -> ...`.

You can use this to simplify your `insert` subroutine (which should probably be called `append` as it always inserts at the tail of the list), to something like

```
subroutine append(the_list, new_node)
  type(list), intent(inout) :: the_list
  type(node), intent(inout), pointer :: new_node
  
  type(node), pointer :: current
  
  ! Find the tail of the list
  current => the_list%head
  do while (associated(current))
    current => current%next
  enddo
  
  ! Insert the new element
  call insert_node(current, new_node)
end subroutine
```

Now you can write an `insert` which keeps things in ascending order, by running through the list and finding where you need to insert, like

```
subroutine insert_ascending(the_list, new_node)
  type(list), intent(inout) :: the_list
  type(node), intent(inout), pointer :: new_node
  
  type(node), pointer :: current
  
  ! Find the first node with value greater than new_node%value
  current => the_list%head
  do while (associated(current))
    if (current%value>new_node%value)
      exit
    endif
    current => current%next
  enddo
  
  ! Insert the new element
  call insert_node(current, new_node)
end subroutine
```

If you want a subroutine which takes `value` as an argument rather than a node, then you need to create the node from the integer and then call an insert subroutine, e.g.

```
subroutine insert_integer(old, new)
  type(node), pointer, intent(inout) :: old
  integer, intent(in) :: new
  
  type(node), pointer :: new_node
  
  allocate(new_node)
  new_node%value = new
  
  call insert_node(old, new_node)
end subroutine
```